# Redux Saga (TypeScript): Prettier extension adds semicolons to the ActionType definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga, prettier

I noticed that prettier replaces the commas with semicolons, which are for example in my ActionType definitions (written in TypeScript). Is this a problem? If so, how can I prevent that? I don't find any possibilities for this in the Prettier settings :(

**For example:**

```
function* mySaga(action: ReturnType<ActionType<{id: string, isFormated: boolean}>>)
```

..becomes

```
function* mySaga(action: ReturnType<ActionType<{id: string; isFormated: boolean}>>)
```

Comment: It's not the issue. Object interface values can be separated by comma or `;`. Prettier inline interfaces like to separate by ';'.

Comment: @KiraLT So it is certainly not a problem or can / should not be changed?

Comment: Yes. According to prettier: "No need to discuss style in code review". So you can leave defaults and it will work without the issue. Well, in my case the only setting I use `"semi": false`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the information. I would be interested in further opinions on this topic. After all, it makes a difference when everyone on the team has a different style. The funny thing is that we have the same prettier config..

Comment: Well, you can start a discussion: Semicolons or no Semicolons. I can guarantee that it will start a fight. That is why prettier is awesome. You can use the default config, write without semicolons and prettier will add semicons.